# Expectation of the product of Brownian motions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I'm new to Stack Exchange. I'd like to find the expectation of the product of three Brownian motions:

$E(B(t_1)B(t_2)B(t_3))$

I know from a previous post here that

$E(B(t_1)B(t_2)B(t_3)B(t_4))=2t_1t_2+t_1t_3$

I know that $E(B_tB_s) = min${$s,t$} and $E(B_t) = 0$.

Comment: Most direct: the distribution of $(B(t_1),B(t_2),B(t_3))$ is invariant by the transformation $(x,y,z)\mapsto(-x,-y,-z)$ hence $E(B(t_1)B(t_2)B(t_3))=-E(B(t_1)B(t_2)B(t_3)=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution I: (Similar to @Did's suggestion)**

Set $x := \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} B_{t_3})$. Then, since $(-B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Brownian motion, we get

$$x = \mathbb{E}((-B_{t_1}) \cdot (-B_{t_2}) \cdot (-B_{t_3})) = - \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} B_{t_3}) = -x;$$

hence, $x=0$.

**Solution 2:**

Suppose (without loss of generality) that $t_1 \leq t_2 \leq t_3$. Recall that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(B_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ are martingales. It follows from the tower property that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} B_{t_3}) &= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} B_{t_3} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_2})] \\ &= \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(B_{t_3} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_2})}_{B_{t_2}}) \\ &= \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2}^2). \end{align*}$$

(Here we have used that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale.) Using the fact that $(B_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2} B_{t_3}) &= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} B_{t_2}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_1})] \\ &= \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1} (B_{t_1}^2-(t_1-t_2)) \\ &= 0 \end{align*}$$

as $\mathbb{E}(B_{t_1}) = \mathbb{E}(B_{t_1}^3)=0$.

Comment: +1. But why "similar"? :-)

Comment: @Did Thanks for your upvote. Similar: Well, because your comment is somehow more accurate - we do not need that $(-B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion; only that $(-B_{t_1},-B_{t_2},-B_{t_3}) \sim (B_{t_1},B_{t_2},B_{t_3})$.

Comment: Right, I had missed the difference.