# Is the expected value of wiener processes multiplied zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

So, I have a standard Wiener process, and $l_3>l_2>l_1>0$, and I would like to calculate $\mathbb{E}(W_{l_1}W_{l_2}W_{l_3})$.

I got that it's zero, is the solution good? I have a solution for it, but I’d be wondering how else it does?!

Comment: How did you get 0?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303933/expectation-of-the-product-of-brownian-motions

Comment: thank you very much! :)